# How to set up a timer for an android game ?

Tags: android, countdowntimer, android-handler

I want to programm a game for Android.

Play principle: The user should have a short time to choose the correct answer.

My problem is the combination between the input (choosing the answer) and the time (countdown). I tried to run a thread, but the thread isn't stoppable. So the user gives the answer, the next activity will be shown and after a while (when the "timer" becomes 0) the activity will be shown again.

- How could I implement this in a correct way?
- Should I use `Thread, Handler, CountDownTimer` ?

Comment: You should show so cade you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a running timer using this on init:

```
Timer updateTimer = new Timer("update");
updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
    updateGUI();
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then in a Thread:

```
//Clock update
currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
clock.setText(sdf.format(currentTime));
clock.invalidate();
```

You could stop the Thread with a boolean inside or outside as you please?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know the specific libraries to use, and I haven't done any thread programming myself, but I would think of the program as a state machine. I hope it helps :/

Set up a `boolean userHasAnswered = false`.

Set up a specialized listener (e.g. touch listener for some button) for answers.
If the listener gets an appropriate response from the user, set `userHasAnswered = true`.

When question loads up, start the thread which counts down.

If user fails to give ans when the time reaches zero, just call `loadNextQuestion()`.

In your thread, do periodic checks every few units of time to see if `userHasAnswered == true`, and if it is true, then call `updateScore()` and `loadNextQuestion()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [alarm manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)